# YAML Problem with single quotes unexpected scalar at node end

Tags: java, spring, yaml

I am reading an `application.yml` file in my java Spring application, and getting this property called body to send in a request (it is a very very long json), sometimes it contains names or values like you will see in the example ahead, and it messes up the yml, any way to solve this so that it takes the json properly? Here is a little example of the kind of data that messes my application.yml (that comes inside that very big json):

```
data:
  body: '{"name":"O'brien"}'
```

The problem is the ' in the persons name

I tried using: `<%='putting the very big json here'%>` but then I get `"Nested mappings are not allowed in compact mappings"`, also tried
`<%=very big json%>` but get the same error

Comment: if very long json, why do you put it as string in yml file? You can put the json in a json file. Also you can create the whole JSON in yml format without the quote. eg: `data:\n  body:\n    name: "O'brien"\n    age: 20`

Comment: It is very easy to use @Value("${data.body}") that is why I prefer it on the yml file

Comment: you can use `@Value("${data.body}"`  on object too. It will create the whole thing instantly. More manageable.

Comment: @Popeye thank you for the idea to read from a .json file, it is working like this, but im leaving the question open if someone wants to clear how to make it work with the yml